# Can i use Eureka Client and Ribbon with spring 3.1 to access other microservice registered using Eureka?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I am having spring 3.1 based web application and i want to write new module as a microservice with spring-boot. I am new to this microservice world, so I have few doubts regarding communication between these two services.

I am thinking to use eureka client with my existing application to access other microservice. I am not sure whether eureka client support spring 3.1 and ribbon client.

Any pointer will be helpful....

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot do this, essentially the spring boot auto-configuration are based on the spring `@Conditional` functionality which are introduced in spring 4.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Need implement it without auto-configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for my current company, that makes it possible to communicate from a spring 3.1.x based application with eureka and other microservices using the resttemplate (with ribbon etc. - just like the loadbalanced resttemplate in spring boot applications). We are in progress of releasing that as open source, you may find it soon here: https://github.com/dm-drogeriemarkt (as spring3-eureka-ribbon something)